# Firestore ArrayUnion Adds Duplicates

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am using Firestore to store array of messages in a chat app.  For each message send, I update my message array with "arrayUnion." On update, sometimes two items will be added (to the client DB, and quickly be overriden by server)

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data): "arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already present". However, my case I see that my client Firebase DB instance will add duplicate data, and then the server will correct this upon successful write, and dedup.

```
  db.update({
    messages: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(serverMessage)
  })
```

For ~1 second, I have duplicate items in arrays. I'm not sure why my data is being duplicated (I have validated that I only have one listener on the client) --- but I also don't understand why the client Firebase db instance allows for the duplicate write.  Here's a [visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWYVL.png) of the errors I'm seeing.

Comment: It is because only the server prevents duplicate and the local real-time update is causing the issue.